# systemd-run does not set environment variables when using --setenv

Tags: linux, systemd

According to the systemd-run documentation, the `-setenv` option can be used to "Run the service process with the specified environment variables set".

However, it seems like the environment variable is actually not available to the process:

```
# systemd-run -t --setenv=TEST=Success echo TEST:$TEST
Running as unit run-20705.service.
Press ^] three times within 1s to disconnect TTY.
TEST:
```

Am I misunderstanding the usage of the `--setenv` option? Running systemd version 219.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prevent bash from resolving `$TEST` before the systemd command is run.

Also echo is incapable of resolving environmental variables. Bash is needed within the systemd process to resolve TEST

So you need to run the following:

```
systemd-run -t --setenv=TEST=Success 'bash -c echo TEST:$TEST'
```

Comment: Heh - can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Comment: Using `set -x` can help with debugging bash